# HAProxy: Return client IP without a backend

Tags: haproxy

How can I configure HAProxy to return the client's public IP in an HTTP response? I don't want to use an upstream backend. I just want requests to `ip.foo.com` to be sent a 204 response with a `Client-IP: 1.2.3.4` response header.